# How to plot a 2-D graph for a induced velocity function in terms of two variables as shown here?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am reading a technical paper and trying to reproduce a graph corresponding to the following function:

[image]

K(x) and E(x) are Legendre's elliptical integrals of the first and second kind respectively. The plot of `V_r` looks like the following:

[image]

I tried to plot this function in Python and here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special


def x(r,z,R):
    return np.sqrt((-4*r*R)/((R-r)**2+z**2))


def V_z(Gamma,R,r,z):
    
    return (-Gamma/4*np.pi)*((2/np.sqrt((R-r)**2+z**2))*(special.ellipk(x(r,z,R))+\
                 (R**2-r**2-z**2)/((R+r)**2+z**2) * special.ellipe(x(r,z,R))))


def V_r(Gamma,R,r,z):
    
    return (-Gamma/4*np.pi)*((4*R*z*np.sqrt((R+r)**2+z**2)/((R+r)**4+z**2*(2*(R+r)**2+z**2)) \
                              * np.sqrt((R+r)**2+z**2)/((R-r)**2+z**2)))*special.ellipe(x(r,z,R))


r = np.linspace(-5,5,100);
z = np.linspace(-5,5,100);

V_z_list = []
for i in V_z(0.1,1,r,z):
    if np.isnan(i).any() == False:
        print(i)
        V_z_list.append(i)


V_r_list = []
for i in V_r(0.1,1,r,z):
    if np.isnan(i).any() == False:
        print(i)
        V_r_list.append(i)


plt.plot(V_z_list)
```

However, I'm getting this graph as a result:

[image]

Could someone help me fix my code?

Comment: You wrote _"The plot of `V_r` looks like the following"_ BUT the _y_-axis in the exemplar graph is labeled `V_z`. Please correct one of the two…